# How can I do pagination?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, axios, request

What will be better? Make 1 request and get all articles for all pages or make a request for each page as needed? Now I am using second variant (make a request for each page as needed). What will be better?

P.S. After the request, all data will be written to Redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually better to paginate your results, otherwise you load an important amount of data for nothing, which can be slow if the user has limited bandwith. Very large quantities of data loaded in a web browser can also slow down the browser itself in some cases.

If your calls to get the results of 1 page take too long when browsing multiple pages, you could load 2 pages at once and have your UI immediately display the second page when the user clicks on 'next', while contacting the backend to get the 3rd page. That way you keep a reactive UI, while only loading what's necessary.